# when adding a title that stores in database, create slug automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a basic insert record that inserts the data captured by a user into the database. It is a very simple form with a title, article and date. I want to create a slug entry as well though. So, if I type: this is a news title then I want it store that in the title column but also store, this-is-a-news-title in the slug column.

I'm using this which does work for creating the hyphens:

```
function create_url_slug($string){
   $slug=preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]+/', '-', $string);
   return $slug;
}
```

And I have an insert like this:

```
$hostname_slugs = "localhost";
$database_slugs = "slugs";
$username_slugs = "root";
$password_slugs = "root";
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=$hostname_slugs;dbname=$database_slugs', '$username_slugs', '$password_slugs');

    $slug = create_url_slug($_POST['newsarticle']);

    //we'll use a prepared statement, which will sanitize our strings for us!
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO news (articledate, newsheadline, headlineslug, newsarticle) VALUES (:articledate, :newsheadline, :headlineslug, :newsarticle)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':articledate', $_POST['articledate']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':newsheadline', $_POST['newsheadline']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':headlineslug', $_POST['headlineslug']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':newsarticle', $slug);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'Successfully saved article!';

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "There was an error: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

But I am not sure how to achieve what I want.

Comment: If you're using DreamWeaver to write your SQL code you have **massive** problems. Please, don't.

Comment: Hi. Yes, I am using dreamweaver. Why do you say I shouldn't?

Comment: The SQL interface layer in that thing is scary out of date and shouldn't be used in production code. In fact, any of the PHP code emitted automatically by DreamWeaver is of extremely dubious quality. A modern interface like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/), and because of the way it's significantly less code to do things is a lot easier to read.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I will def check it out.

Comment: DreamWeaver is very much a product of the 1990s and a lot of the PHP internals reflect that. If you're looking for a more modern approach to developing applications, look at various 
[development frameworks](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) and pick one that suits your style and needs. These offer significantly more functionality than what DreamWeaver can do out of the box.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info. I am keen to check it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have the `headline` slug, which is what you want anyway. right? So let's just wrap that in our function `create_url_slug()`

```
create_url_slug(GetSQLValueString($_POST['headlineslug'], "text"))
```

Should be all you need.

Let's do it using PDO as the gentlemen above suggested!

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=yourdatabasename', 'user', 'pass');

    $slug = create_url_slug($_POST['newsarticle']);

    //we'll use a prepared statement, which will sanitize our strings for us!
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO news (articledate, newsheadline, headlineslug, newsarticle) VALUES (:articledate, :newsheadline, :headlineslug, :newsarticle)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':articledate', $_POST['articledate']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':newsheadline', $_POST['newsheadline']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':headlineslug', $_POST['headlineslug']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':newsarticle', $slug);

    $stmt->execute();

    echo 'Successfully saved article!';

} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo "There was an error: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}
```

**Resources**

1. [PDO connection](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)
2. [PDO Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Sorry, I am not very good at explaining. I want the headline to not have any hyphens in so when you view the article, the actual heading on the page doesn't-look-like-this. I just want the actual url to have the hyphens. So, that is why i have 2 fields. The 'newsheadline' which will display on the page without hyphens and the 'headlineslug' field which will be used for the url. However, I don't want to have to type everything in twice

Comment: i.e.: type the article heading in and then have to type the same thing in with hyphens. I want to type the heading in, submit the form and it must then take that and insert the hyphens and store that in the slug field (headlineslug)

Comment: @Jonathon That is precisely what my code is doing above. Where is the confusion?

Comment: Sorry, it gives me an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' 'my second post')' at line 1

Comment: @Jonathon I've given you the PDO way of storing this. I am not familiar with DreamWeaver's SQL code, and the gentlemen was right, we shouldn't use it. Please observe the new method.

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance as I usually used Dreamweaver. I am getting this error and I will update code now in first post for you: There was an error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host '$hostname_slugs' (22)

Comment: The server host is typically `localhost`.

Comment: Tried that. Getting new error now: There was an error: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user '$username_slugs'@'localhost' (using password: YES)